# Is there a native YAML library for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, yaml

I'm considering using YAML as part of my next iPhone application, but I haven't been able to find an Objective-C library to use.

The Wikipedia page for YAML [mentions one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Implementations_and_Bindings), but the link is dead.

**Is there an Objective-C library that can parse YAML into native collection objects (NSArray, NSDictionary, etc...)?**

Comment: +1 just for desire to use YAML

Comment: have you found a solution? I have tried YAMLKit but I can't make it work with iOS.

Comment: @MikeBevz I haven't found a solution. I ended up just using JSON in that project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The Cocoa extensions for Syck](http://github.com/indeyets/syck/tree/master/ext/cocoa/src/) are probably what you're looking for -- it's where the library that Shaggy Frog mentioned seems to be living these days.

Answer (score 6):

You can try [YAML.framework](http://github.com/mirek/YAML.framework) it's LibYAML based, it's fast and easy to use. Follows the same pattern as standard NSPropertyListSerialization.

You can use it for iOS (iPhone/iPad) development.

Comment: Hi, I tried yaml.framework, and had problems with serialisation: It uses UTF16 even though it attempts to set utf8. I've since had more luck with yamlkit.

Answer (score 5):

The [YAMLKit](http://github.com/patrickt/yamlkit) framework is a thin wrapper around [LibYAML](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/LibYAML). It does exactly what you want. For example:

```
[[YKParser alloc] init];
[p readString:@"- foo\n- bar\n- baz"];
id result = [p parse];
/* result is now an NSArray containing an NSArray with elements:
   @"foo", @"bar", @"baz" */
[p release];
```

Comment: YAMLKit doesn't include libyaml, so you need to grab that yourself. This approach is a bit cleaner, but also a bit more troublesome.

Answer (score 3):

I recently wrote modern ObjC-YAML bindings, based on the standard NSCoder/NSKeyedArchiver interface: http://github.com/th-in-gs/YACYAML.  I'm using them in my own projects, and intend to maintain them for at least as long as I continue to do so.

More here: http://www.blog.montgomerie.net/yacyaml

Comment: Good job! I looked through it and found it most powerful.

Comment: This is my favorite implementation. Using NSCoding to serialize/deserialize objects to/from YAML seems like the right to do it.

Answer (score 1):

***IF*** you are doing alot of ***c++*** in your iPhone projects, then please have a look at ***yaml-cpp***:

http://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/

1. has native iPhone support (via it's cmake build system)
2. has no dependencies beyond a good compiler and cmake
3. is very c++ friendly (thus, the name) with solid documentation (see the wiki/HowToParseADocument page)

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](http://will.thimbleby.net/yaml.html) right from [YAML's front page](http://www.yaml.org/). But it looks like it might be out of date (c. 2004?), and the CVS link doesn't work for me.

I would bet that it's just a thin wrapper around an underlying C library like [this](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/LibYAML) or [this](http://github.com/gitpan/YAML-Syck)... C code being "native" code that the Objective-C compiler will grok.

Comment: Yeah, that's essentially what I'd like. I know I could just use the C or C++ YAML parsers, but I would really like to have the wrapper around it that returns the right collections and NSStrings rather than char*

Comment: I hear what you're saying. Unfortunately, it looks like there's no one making that wrapper anymore. I'd follow up with their mailing list directly... maybe someone's got one tucked away that they haven't released yet.

Answer (score -1):

I found this question looking for YAML + objective C options. I ended up using this solution: https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel. Very cool, up to date and easy to use. Parses yaml directly into objective C models that you create inheriting the JSONModel class.

Comment: Is this true? I don't see any mention of yaml in that project.