# Yaml parser for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode6, yaml

I'm looking for a Yaml parser for iOS, to get my Yaml data into dictionary.

I Found already this question asked here : [Yaml parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909538/is-there-a-native-yaml-library-for-iphone)

But, it seems that all these Frameworks are old, and contain ARC compatibility errors.

Have you any idea about which framework to use with xcode 6 and how can I make it functional.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found through the Pod library, a good Yaml parser.
it's called Yaml-framework, To install it :

```
pod 'YAML-Framework'
```

Example of usage :

```
NSMutableDictionary* yaml = [YAMLSerialization objectWithYAMLStream: stream
                                                      options: kYAMLReadOptionStringScalars
                                                        error: &e];
```

Hope that helps other who are looking for the same thing.

Regards